# Installation of Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 64bit version in my pc alongside Windows 7 64bit OS. So I have installed Windows 7 and now when I tried to install Ubuntu, it doesn't detect any OS and shows it doesn`t have any OS. What to do now?

Answer (score -3):

First you need to create a new partition from windows for installing ubuntu (around 20 GB) or more if you need

Then follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) instruction 
To install ubuntu alongside windows.

Comment: thanx 4 ur advice ... i will try it and let u know...